# Decrypt GPG file | Python | AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I receive a encrypted file from EFS, my lambda function should decrypt the GPG file(I have the key with me) and send it to S3 bucket.

After reading few blogs I wrote the below code(still did not test it).

```
import boto3
import gnupg

# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    Key = "/efs/iamfile.txt"
    stream = open(Key, "rb")
    decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt_file(stream)
    bucketName = "op-efs-vpc"
    outPutname = "decrypted_data"
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_file(Key,bucketName,outPutname)
```

Python -pnupg to decrypt a file code:-

```
import os
import gnupg


def initialize_gpg(key_paths):
    gpg = gnupg.GPG()
    for path in key_paths:
        key_data = open(path).read()
        gpg.import_keys(key_data)
    # return
    return gpg


def remove_gpg_from_path(path):
    """
    We expect the given path as argument to have the form: file-name.ext.gpg
    So we want to return: file-name.ext
    For example:
        input: bottles.csv.gpg
        output: bottles.csv
    """
    return os.path.splitext(path)[0]


def decrypt_file(gpg, encrypted_path):
    with open(encrypted_path, 'rb') as a_file:
        decrypted_path = remove_gpg_from_path(encrypted_path)
        gpg.decrypt_file(a_file, output=decrypted_path)
        return decrypted_path
```

How can I integrate both the code together and send decrypted file to S3 AWS bucket and Where should I enter the "Decryption_key" in my code.